# MySql Count Same Column multiple times

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(w.invoiceId) AS '10 Days' FROM tbl_Invoice w
WHERE w.invoiceId NOT IN(
SELECT inv.invoiceId FROM tbl_InvoiceAllocation inv)
AND w.invoiceDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

It works fine and returns a count of all the invoices that have a date of more than 10 days ago. I now want to return counts for invoices that are also more than 20 and 100 days old in the same query. So ideally the query would return something like this:

```
10 Days    20 Days    100 Days

350        280        90
```

Comment: see this , need to left join with the same table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300020/mysql-multiple-counts-in-single-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the COUNT to a SUM, using the specified WHERE clause as a CASE statement, with true values as 1 and false values as 0

Something like

```
SELECT  SUM( CASE WHEN w.invoiceDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10 Days',
        SUM( CASE WHEN w.invoiceDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 20 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '20 Days'
FROM    tbl_Invoice w 
WHERE   w.invoiceId NOT IN( 
                            SELECT  inv.invoiceId 
                            FROM    tbl_InvoiceAllocation inv) 
AND     w.invoiceDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

Comment: thanks this worked but without the 
    AND     w.invoiceDate < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 20 DAY)