# Can I select more counts in one query?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with a field called `type`, where 3 various  rows are possible: `1`, `2` and `3`.

Now, I don't care about `3` at all. I need to count how many rows there are with `type = 1` and with `type = 2`. I am doing this with 2 queries, like this:

Query1: `SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM users WHERE type='1'`
Query2: `SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM users WHERE type='2'`

Can I do this with only 1 single query? If so, should I, or not? How would the query look?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300020/mysql-multiple-counts-in-single-query

Comment: The "easy" ways of doing it in a single query have the disadvantage that the two counts are returned as separate rows and therefore you need additional client code to extract them. The other answers manage to provide the answer as a single row which makes things easier for the client but is probably less efficient on the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT type,
       COUNT(id) AS count
  FROM users
 WHERE type IN ('1','2')
 GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM users
GROUP BY type
HAVING type < 3
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want separate numbers,

```
SELECT SUM(IF(type='1', 1, 0)), SUM(IF(type='2', 1, 0)) 
FROM users WHERE type IN ('1', '2')
```