# MySQL left join counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have a left join to a table and want to count columns from it, after grouping by a column of the parent table:

```
SELECT * , COUNT(list.id) AS listcount, COUNT(uploads.id) AS uploadcount 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN lists ON members.id= list.mid
LEFT JOIN uploads ON members.id= uploads.mid
GROUP BY members.id
```

Assume that a user can have either lists or uploads based on the type of user. Then is above query good enough? If not why?

Or do I have to use this query?

```
SELECT * , l.listcount,   u.uploadcount 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN (select count(lists.id) as listscount,mid from lists group by mid) as l
                                                                on l.mid = m.id
LEFT JOIN (select count(uploads.id) as uploadscount
                           ,mid from uploads group by mid) as u on u.mid = m.id
GROUP BY members.id
```

Or correlated subqueries?

```
SELECT *,
      (select count(lists.id) as listscount from lists as l where l.mid = m.id
       group by mid) as listcount
      (select count(uploads.id) from uploads as u where u.mid = m.id
       group by mid) as uploadscount 
FROM members 
GROUP BY members.id
```

And which is best solution?

Comment: Good enough, good enough for what? Do you get the desired results and do you get them in reasonable time? Then yes, else no.

Comment: It's always recommended to analyze a query using *EXPLAIN* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `m` for members is missing in query 2 and 3. Otherwise they should give the same numbers.

Query 2 (fixed) will perform fastest.

Query 1 is different in that it will give a higher number for `uploads`, if there are cases of multiple `lists` per `member`. After joining to `lists`, there will be multiple rows for a member too, which will increase the count for `uploads`. So **query 1 is probably wrong**.

Also, `NULL` values are **not** counted. The [manual informs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> COUNT(expr)
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.

Comment: Now another question, assume user can have both lists and uploads. Now is 1st query ok?

Comment: @VenuGopalT: Yes. `lists` and `uploads` are independent in all three queries. Now, if you had `LEFT JOIN uploads ON lists.mid= uploads.mid` in query 1, then that would be different: would only give you uploads where there is a list, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300020/mysql-multiple-counts-in-single-query check out this

Comment: But my doubt is why counts are wrong for 1st query even though I am using COUNT(list.id) AS listcount,    COUNT(uploads.id) AS uploadcount. As per document, it should count only uploads.id

Comment: @VenuGopalT: It does. But `uploads.id` my be added multiple times, as I explain in my answer.